# How do I put individual entries in an array into their own arrays with their own variables?

Tags: python

I'm doing a programming task and I'm not the best programmer. I have an array of names and I need to give every name in the array their own array with values in it. Help?

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have to be a lot more specific than that. Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

The obvious way would be to use a *dictionary*

```
result = {}
for name in array_of_names:
    result[name] = [1, 2, 3]
```

If you want to *keep the original order* of the names

```
from collections import OrderedDict
result= OrderedDict()
```

instead of `result = {}`

Then, you can get the new values

```
for name, values in result.items():
    print(name, values)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `defaultdict(list)` and setup each `key` as your `names` and then append whatever values you want to your `keys`

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)

names = ['vash', 'me', 'I']
for i in names:
    dd[i].append(1)
dd['vash'].append(9000)
print(dd)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'vash': [1, 9000], 'me': [1], 'I': [1]})
```